# Using dynamic parameters to call Azure function in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

Powershell is not my expertise. However, I'm trying to make a call to Azure using the following code.

```
function Set-UserAndAttribute
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ObjectID,    
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Attribute,     
        [Parameter(Position=2,mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Value
    )
    
     Connect-Directory
    #The below line is causing the issue. My intention is to use dynamic variable for Attribute. Is there a way to accomplish this?
    Set-AzureAdUser -ObjectID $ObjectID -$Attribute $value 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `Invoke-Expression`

The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command.

So your code would be :

`Invoke-Expression "Set-AzureAdUser -ObjectID $ObjectID -$Attribute $value"`

You are passing the command as a string - this has values populated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the  response. Will give a try with this.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work